# How can I reproduce docker commands seen in docker hub image layers?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I am wondering how it is possible to reproduce the docker commands seen in [this](https://hub.docker.com/layers/cnsun/perses/perses_part_54_name_clang_trunk/images/sha256-246166ae3dfc90207233089d9a89dda8632687be9a1b027e80a37efe20f5a70b?context=explore) docker image. The image copies certain versions of clang and gcc, which is something I wish to do in my own dockerfile. I cannot use the linked docker image, as it contains many commands that are unnecessary for the work I want to do.

The very first command is
`ADD file:2cddee716e84c40540a69c48051bd2dcf6cd3bd02a3e399334e97f20a77126ff in /`

Further down, there are many similar `COPY` commands. I wish to reproduce the following command in my own dockerfile:
`COPY dir:49371ba683da700cabfad7284da39bd2144aa0c46086c3015a74737d7be6b51e in /compilers/clang/3.4.2`

The command copies clang-3.4.2 into the given folder. I am unsure how I can do the same, or even what the hash is/means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried looking, but I couldn't find the Dockerfile used to create the image. There is another way though.

It's quite a large image and I'm on a terrible internet connection, so I haven't tested this myself, but one thing you can do is copy the things you need from the image into a new one of your own like this

```
FROM cnsun/perses:perses_part_54_name_clang_trunk AS original
FROM ubuntu:latest
COPY --from=original /compilers/clang/3.4.2 /compilers/clang/3.4.2
```

You can also copy the files from the image to your computer. Then you can copy them from there into new images without referencing the cnsun image:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/dest --entrypoint /bin/bash cnsun/perses:perses_part_54_name_clang_trunk -c "cp -r /compilers/clang/3.4.2 /dest"
```

This will copy the /compilers/clang/3.4.2 directory into the current directory on the host. If your host is Windows, replace `$(pwd)` with `%cd%`.

Comment: Great suggestion! It works. However, I want to avoid using cnsun/perses as it can take as long as 20mins to finish. Currently, I think it is faster to just download and compile clang-3.4.2

Comment: @ImTryingToLearn I added another option to my answer, where you copy the files to your host